# Floating and Offset Javascript Values

Tags: javascript, offset

I have two items that I am floating right in my XHTML page. Unfortunately, when I try to get the offset of the right most item... it comes back as the position the element would be in if it were not floated.

```
    <div id="Left style="float:right"></div>
    <div id="right" style="float:right"></div> 

    Using Jquery 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
       var right = $("#right"); 
       alert(right[0].offsetLeft); 
    </script>
```

Do I have to do something like this?

```
function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) 
    {
        do 
        {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;

        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you getting the offset of the right-most item??

Comment: And to add to the above comment: what CSS rules do you use to style those divs? In short: do you have an example page (HTML/CSS/JS) so we can see what you tried so far?

Comment: at SO, we are so great, that is supposed to have a magic ball! ;)

Comment: Ok, I updated the question with some example code.

Comment: So do I have to keep going up the parents and adding the offset difference?

Comment: Heh, looks like that is it. I have to find the offsetParents and add up the total offset :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to find the page position.

So yes, you would use a function like:

```
function aGetElementsPagePosition (zElement)
{
    var iLeftOffset = zElement.offsetLeft; 
    var iTopOffset  = zElement.offsetTop;

    while (zElement = zElement.offsetParent)
    {
        iLeftOffset += zElement.offsetLeft;
        iTopOffset  += zElement.offsetTop;
    }

    return [iLeftOffset, iTopOffset];
}
```

Comment: You should check for hasLayout in IE7-. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this:

```
    function findPos(obj) { 
      var pos = new Object();
      pos.x = pos.y = 0;        
      if (obj.offsetParent)  
      { 
        do  
        { 
          pos.x += obj.offsetLeft; 
          pos.y += obj.offsetTop; 
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent); 
      } 
      return pos;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do to get the position of an element in a page, in a cross browser manner is:

```
var tempEl;
var myElement = document.getElementById('#someId');

//cool guys
x = myElement.offsetLeft;
y = myElement.offsetTop;

//IE 7-
if (myElement.hasLayout
    && myElement.offsetParent
    && myElement.offsetParent != document.body
    ) {

    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    tempEl = myElement;

    while (tempEl.parentNode) {

        if (tempEl.currentStyle.hasLayout) {//very important for floated elements
            x += (tempEl.offsetLeft) ? tempEl.offsetLeft : 0;
            y += (tempEl.offsetTop) ? tempEl.offsetTop : 0;
        }

        if (tempEl == document.body) {
            break;
        }

        tempEl = tempEl.parentNode;

    }

}
```